# Вывод слов в текстовую область

Tags: delphi

При помощи компонента Edit ввести в компоненты ListBox слова: в первый – “Я”, “смогу”, “написать”, “любую”, “программу”; во второй – “Хакер”, “все”, “программы”, “переделать”, “стремится”. При помощи кода связать оба компонента ListBox между собой так, чтобы при выборе любого по порядку слова в одном приводило к выбору такого же по порядку слова в другом компоненте, а также оба этих слова появлялись в компоненте Memo (на новой строке).

Comment: Какие еще иди**ы назначают экзамены по Delphi - они что с ума посходили? Это же мертвый язык!

Comment: @Barmaley Ваш комментарий огорчает разработчиков `Skype.`

Comment: Всегда подозревал, что со скайпом что-то неладно :)

Comment: @Barmaley, вас, наверное, обманули. По рейтингу за прошлый год, он по некоторым данным, даже вырос в популярности. [См. тут](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=32812)

Comment: @Dex, у TIOBE несколько сомнительная методика оценки. Скорее всего "популярность" им накрутил небольшой приток нубов, слетевшихся на RAD-сахар, в то время как лояльные пользователи понемногу сваливают.

Comment: @Котик в скайпе же только "рубашка" дельфийская. Или нет?

Comment: @Любовь Головина, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У **`Edit`**'а:

```
Edit.Text := someVar; // пишем someVar в Edit
someVar := Edit.Text; // читаем с Edit в someVar
```

У **`ListBox`**'a:

```
ListBox.Add(someVar); // добавление нового элемента с текстом someVar
selectedItem := ListBox.ItemIndex; // № выбранного элемента (начиная с нуля)
someVar := ListBox.Items[selectedItem]; // значение элемента selectedItem
```

У **`Memo`**:

```
Memo.Add(someVar); // добавление новой строчки с текстом someVar
someVar := Memo.Lines[lineIndex]; // значение строки lineIndex
someVar := Memo.Text; // читаем весь текст с Memo в someVar
Memo.Text := someVar; // записываем someVar в Memo (перезапишется всё)
```

Если понадобится текущая строка в `Memo`, то надо смотреть в сторону `CaretPos`.

А готовое решение подготовьте сами - это поможет не забыть всё на экзамене. Удачи!

Comment: Не кормите, вы отнимаете хлеб у преподавателей и создаёте лишную работу отделам кадров.

Comment: Хорошо, не буду :)